# How do I fix net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR caused by my js code

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm currently having an issue when I call certain function repeatedly (ChartData). The code that calls the function is as follows:

```
  for (let i = 1; i < 3600; i++) {
    setTimeout(function timer() {
      chartserviceApi.ChartData("false").then(responseArr => {
       
        console.log("Here !")
        Chartdata = responseArr.data
        let prpdData = responseArr.data.slice();
        if (Chartdata.length == 0) {
          dataPresent = false;
        }
        if (responseArr.data.find(x => x > 200)) {
          alert('abv 200');
        }

        prpsch1.streamPush(responseArr.data)
        prpdch1.streamPush(prpdData)

        
        const parsedMessage = responseArr.data
        const keys = Object.keys(parsedMessage)
        let dataPackage = parsedMessage[keys[keys.length - 1]]
        console.log(dataPackage)
        //prpsch1.streamPush(dataPackage[0]);
        prpdch1.streamPush(dataPackage[0]);
        prpsch1.consume();
        prpdch1.consume();
        prpsch1.runStream();
        prpdch1.runStream();
      });
    }, 4000);}
```

The ChartData function is as the following:

```
import axios from 'axios';
const Chartdata = 0
export default {
  ChartData(param) {
    if (param == "false") {
      console.log("False!")
      return axios.get('https://localhost:3000/api/Sensor/GetSensorDataQ?id=1&isInitiated=false');
    }
    else {
      console.log(param)
      console.log("True!")
      return axios.get('https://localhost:3000/api/Sensor/GetSensorDataQ?id=1&isInitiated=true');
    }
  }
```

Then I get these errors repeatedly.
[image]

Can anyone suggest what to do here?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Can you access that url in the browser? I am afraid that the problem is actually from the url that the service is not running. Because it's localhost and you need to make sure that the api is running normally.

Comment: You might be calling the API too often for the browser to handle

Comment: @DhanaD. I can access the url in my browser. It's just that the api doesn't run.

Comment: @TylerLiu I think you might be right. Do you have an idea to deal with such situation if the api is called too often?

Comment: Can you try using a different browser and see what happens?

Comment: I've changed the browser to chrome and now am getting the error "net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR".

Comment: @Taki try updating your api services' threshold to just over the amount you want per second `n + 2`

Comment: Hey @Abdusalammohamed I didn't quite get what you are referring to as 'api servcies' threshold' . Can you identify it as the variable from my code? Or perhaps, you can show the code that you want me to fix.

Comment: @Taki threshold means the number of time an API gets called per second AKA Rate Limiting, currently you are sending one request every four seconds which is good i guess if your API's threshold is not set to for example, one request per 5 seconds... in which you might get a HTTP 429 (Too many attempts!) error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change https protocol with http in your url. Because https protocol need ssl certificate.